# Does FlinkSQL support column name aliasing?

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

To be more specific, I'm trying to make a Join while changing the column names,

```
IE
CREATE TABLE cars (
  id BIGINT
  ) WITH (
);

CREATE TABLE car_dealers (
  id BIGINT,
  car_id
  ) WITH (
);

CREATE TABLE car_aggregate (
  car BIGINT,
  dealer BIGINT
  ) WITH (
);

INSERT INTO car_aggregate
SELECT
  c.id AS car,
  d.id AS dealer
FROM
  cars as c
INNER JOIN
  car_dealers as d on c.id = d.car_id;
```

I've tried just the selct query, but I'm getting two columsn with no values. wondering if it should be working and I'm just missing something

Comment: Apparently, query *works* - otherwise, you'd get an **error**. Result you got means that there are no rows in source tables that can be joined on columns you used, i.e. C.ID = D.CAR_ID. Can you verify that such rows actually exist?

Comment: you have created `cars` but selecting from `car`

Comment: typo in the code

Comment: @Littlefoot Ive verified the columns exists, and have matching values. The example I gave above was also just an example, but I've edited the name for clarity

Comment: The datatype for `car_id` in the table `car_dealers` is missing. (but that probably is a typo:  see: [Proofread](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Proofread%20before%20posting!), but typo's can still happen...)  Secondly: "Ive verified the columns exists, and have matching values."  But you never show **any** values, so how can anyone see what **you** think **you** are missing ?